# Bitbucket Pipeline configuration for more than one AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a Bitbucket Pipeline configured for one AWS account working just fine. Lets call this account "account 1".

I've added a second branch to my bitbucket-pipelines.yml and this branch should deploy to a different AWS account than "account 1".

The issue I am having is that in "Environment variables" in Bitbucket, I have "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" and "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" for "account 1".

How can I add new keys for another AWS account so that both AWS accounts work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

you will have to add two more variables into your repository variables/Environment variables for your second account for ex -

ACCOUNT2_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID

ACCOUNT2_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

so far you can use them under the script section inside your second branch pipeline configuration -

```
script:
  - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$ACCOUNT2_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
  - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$ACCOUNT2_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

An example configured with two AWS account.

```
.
.
.
pipelines:
  branches:
    branch_account1:
      - step:
         name: "Deploy on Acccount 1"
         script:
           - export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=$ACCOUNT1_DEFAILT_REGION
           - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$ACCOUNT1_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
           - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$ACCOUNT1_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
           - deploy script

    branch_account2:
      - step:
        name: "Deploy on Acccount 2"
        script:
          - export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=$ACCOUNT2_DEFAILT_REGION
          - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$ACCOUNT2_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
          - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$ACCOUNT2_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
          - deploy script
    .
    .
    .
```